# Automatically hibernate save relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Basically my question is why if I have an Hibernate relationship like this one.

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "candidacy_id", nullable = false)
@XmlElement
@JsonIgnore
@Getter
@Setter
private List<EvaluationSelectionCriteria> evaluationSelectionCriterias = new ArrayList<>();

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "candidacy_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
   @XmlTransient
  @Getter
  @Setter
   private Candidacy candidacy;
```

Why if I do this candidacy.setEvaluationSelectionCriteria(list) automatically this list is persisted in database?

I would like to use the EvaluationSelectionCriteria as a repository to render a list of "future" EvaluationSelectionCriteria

Could be because is not Lazy?

More detail explanation

So would be like I call method a, there I´m get from database entity A then I set a list into A and then I return A in the method but I´m not saving A, when I see the value of the list already have ids!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the list to be saved when the parent entity is saved/merged, you should remove or restrict the cascade setting for the relationship:

```
@OneToMany
private List<EvaluationSelectionCriteria> evaluationSelectionCriterias
```

or

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE) // or other values from the enum
private List<EvaluationSelectionCriteria> evaluationSelectionCriterias
```

**EDIT**: If you want to fetch an entity in a transactional method and modify it, you can restrict the scope of the transaction to the fetching only. Then modify the entity outside the transactional method. Later, you can merge the detached entity if needed.

Since collection attributes are lazy per default you will either need to

- access their content while still inside the transactional method - so the collection can be fetched from the DB. Please note that you will have to call a method on the collection that actualy requires it's content to be loaded, like `getCriterias().size()`.
- use `LEFT JOIN FETCH` to load the collection as a side effect of the query.

I would not modify the `FlushMode` for the session - while this would probably work, it feels like a kludge - it does not communicate your intent very well. Explicitly fetching the collection and modifying it outside the transaction expresses your intent better IMO.

Comment: My guess was that the contents of the list should saved to the DB on demand only. Without a cascade, the OP will have to save the elements of the list first.

Comment: No, no that part is clear. Here the weird thing is that I´m not saving the entity. I just set the list into the entity and then I return the entity but I´m not saving. The only thing is that my whole service is transactional, but in any moment I´m saving the entity. So would be like I call method a, there I´m get from database entity A then I set a list into A and then I return A in the method but I´m not saving A, when I see the value of the list already have ids!!!

Comment: setting the flush mode of your session to manual should avoid the auto persitance of the list sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);

Comment: Ah, ok - I seem to understand your requirement better. The code that you have posted implies that there is a join table between you entity (A) and the EvaluationSelectionCriteria, since there is no `mappedBy` attribute on the relationship mapping. Is this correct? Do you reference A from the EvaluationSelectionCriteria?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I forgot to say that I´m using Spring, so finally I add the @Transactional(readOnly=true) into my method instead in the service class level.